# Python script to execute remote command in background and get pid

Tags: python, subprocess

I have tried with subprocess and sshpass to execute remote command. Here is my code to execute remote command using subprocess..

```
import subprocess
import sys

HOST="192.168.20.175"
COMMAND="cat /proc/meminfo | grep MemTotal"

ssh = subprocess.Popen(["sshpass", "-p", "unlock123",
                        "ssh", "%s" % HOST, COMMAND],
                        shell=False,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
result = ssh.stdout.readlines()

if result == []:
    error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
    print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
    print result

print "Return Code - %s" % ssh.returncode
```

However,

1. returncode returns None
2. Now I want to run following loop command on remote machine

`"echo"; while true; do ps -p 1820 -o %cpu,%mem | grep -v CPU >> /tmp/proc_out.log;`

3. I want to start the command on remote machine and don't want to wait for the command to complete.
4. Once the command is fired, get the pid of the command
5. Kill the process after some time whenever required.

Is there any possible solution for this?

Comment: There's more bash than python. Did you think about converting it to bash script ? If you wanna stick to python, then one of the solutions is fabric, its made to do this type of things.

Comment: +1 on [fabric](http://fabfile.org). note: use `pty=False` to run a background job.

Comment: unrelated: if the subprocess generates enough output on stderr then it hangs -- you should read from *both* streams concurrently (threads or async.io) to avoid it (there are **5** warnings in the docs about it!). Call `out, err = p.communicate()` or `rc = p.wait()` (`p.poll()`) if you want non-None `p.returncode`.

Comment: you need also to understand what `nohup`, `disown` do, to run background jobs. And what are session, process groups, to kill the whole process trees.